# Repository not using tenant database in Abp multitenant application

Tags: c#, asp.net, repository-pattern, multi-tenant, dbcontext

I'm building a multitenant application using ABP.io (non commercial) and I've got the migrator service adding a database per tenant. I ended up making a injectableDbContextFactory that gets the tenant string from the tenant repository.

```
public class InjectableCloudDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<CloudDbContext>, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly ICurrentTenant _tenant;
    private readonly ITenantStore _tenantStore;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public InjectableCloudDbContextFactory(ICurrentTenant tenant, ITenantStore tenantStore,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _tenant = tenant;
        _tenantStore = tenantStore;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    //This one is used by our migration service
    public CloudDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
        var tenantId = _tenant.Id;
        if (tenantId.HasValue)
        {
            var tenant = _tenantStore.Find(tenantId.Value);

            var tenantConnectionStrings = tenant.ConnectionStrings
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .ToList();
            if (tenantConnectionStrings.Count >= 1)
            {
                connectionString = tenantConnectionStrings.First();
            }
        }


        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CloudDbContext>()
            //this needs to get connection string for each tenant - this might work!?
            .UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new CloudDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

the schema migrator then runs for each tenant and produces the tenant db with tables.

```
public class EntityFrameworkCoreV2DbSchemaMigrator
    : IV2DbSchemaMigrator, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly InjectableCloudDbContextFactory _contextFactory;

    public EntityFrameworkCoreV2DbSchemaMigrator(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider, InjectableCloudDbContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public async Task MigrateAsync()
    {
        await _contextFactory.CreateDbContext().Database.MigrateAsync();
    }
}
```

However when my Data seeder accesses the Jobs Repository to add data it puts everything in the first 'default' db regardless of the currentTenant (which debugging has shown is being set).

I thought the repository was supposed to get the right dBContext automatically.

I have tried doing OnConffiguring in the dbCOntext rather than the factory and tried using

```
await _serviceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<ClikHostDbContext>()
            .Database
            .MigrateAsync();
```

instead of injecting my dbContextFactory.